# Why do I get an 'Insufficient Privilege' when accepting Salesforce to Salesforce invitation?

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

Why do I get an 'Insufficient Privilege' when accepting Salesforce to Salesforce invitation?

I am the system admin and the register owner of the receiving ORG.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was missing>

Salesforce to Salesforce setting should be enabled by putting a tick on the Checkbox